# Pointer events allow on certain items

Tags: css

i have a navigation bar that runs the whole way across the bottom of my page i am using pointer events so allow users to click through the navigation bar but i have images with links that now dont work as there is a pointer-events: none;.

How would i allow pointer events on my images in my footer but not the footer itself?

```
#footer {
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    height:80px;
    width:100%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    background-position: top !important;
     pointer-events:none;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#footer a {
  pointer-events:  auto;
}
```